# mod_rewrite mysteriously appends subfolder to rewritten url

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, apache-2.4

**EDIT: [Solved]** Finally found the solution in the documentation; posted an answer. In short: the `DPI` flag.

**EDIT:** at the bottom, added an easy way to reproduce the problem online.

I've spent a few hours debugging some rewrites. All is well except one behavior that stumps me.

Somehow, when fed a url with two or more subdirectories, mod_rewrite automatically appends all subdirectories (except the first) to the rewritten url. Here is the simplest example I could reduce it to. This is in an htaccess at `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.

- url: `http://localhost/stripthis/stripthat`
- `RewriteRule ^ RewriteWasHere_`
- Output: `RewriteWasHere_/stripthat`

Where did that `stripthat` come from? Could some option upstream be causing this?

I have tried to strip the subfolders with a variety of rules. For instance:

- url: `http://localhost/stripthis/stripthat`
- `RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+) RewriteWasHere_$1`
- Output: `RewriteWasHere_stripthis/stripthat`

Strangely, this happens both on a local xampp x Apache 2.4.7 and a remote CentOS x Apache 2.2.

I have been inspecting the rewritten urls by outputting them to a script, but here's a way to reproduce the problem online.

**How to Reproduce This Online**

- Go to this [online htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)
- For the url, enter `http://example.com/a/123/b`

For the rules, paste this:

```
# the `(?!)` negative lookaheads are just to make triple sure
# we're not running the same rules multiple times
RewriteRule ^(?!m[yo])([^/]+) my_$1
#RewriteRule ^(?!mo])\D*(\d+) mo_$1:$1:$1
```

1. Run: the output is `http://example.com/my_a/123/b`
2. Uncomment the second line.
3. Run: the output is `http://example.com/mo_123:123:123/b`
4. Comment out the second line, change the first line to `RewriteRule ^(?!m[yo])([^/]+).*$ my_$1`: the problem goes away on this site, but not on my servers.

Any insights would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: +1 Interesting problem, I will try to reproduce it on my Apache.

Comment: @anubhava I spent a couple hours playing with it... Even if you think you are stripping everything with a `ReWriteRule (?!hey) hey`, it the next rule you are still able to find digits in the subpath with `ReWriteRule (?!ho)\D*(\d+) ho_$1_digits`

Comment: @anubhava Found it! Went back to the documentation, and... the `DPI` flag (`discardpathinfo`) takes care of it. Thank you so much for your time, though. :)

Answer (score 3):

**[DPI] (discardpathinfo)**

After hours of tests and puzzlement, I went back to [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html) and found the solution: the `[DPI]` flag.

> The DPI flag causes the PATH_INFO portion of the rewritten URI to be
>   discarded.
>
> This flag is available in version 2.2.12 and later.
>
> In per-directory context, the URI each RewriteRule compares against is
>   the concatenation of the current values of the URI and PATH_INFO.
>
> The current URI can be the initial URI as requested by the client, the
>   result of a previous round of mod_rewrite processing, or the result of
>   a prior rule in the current round of mod_rewrite processing.
>
> In contrast, the PATH_INFO that is appended to the URI before each
>   rule reflects only the value of PATH_INFO before this round of
>   mod_rewrite processing. As a consequence, if large portions of the URI
>   are matched and copied into a substitution in multiple RewriteRule
>   directives, without regard for which parts of the URI came from the
>   current PATH_INFO, the final URI may have multiple copies of PATH_INFO
>   appended to it.
>
> Use this flag on any substitution where the PATH_INFO that resulted
>   from the previous mapping of this request to the filesystem is not of
>   interest. This flag permanently forgets the PATH_INFO established
>   before this round of mod_rewrite processing began. PATH_INFO will not
>   be recalculated until the current round of mod_rewrite processing
>   completes. Subsequent rules during this round of processing will see
>   only the direct result of substitutions, without any PATH_INFO
>   appended.

Comment: +1 very nice find on this under utilized flag.

Comment: @anubhava It's amazing. I can barely believe that the solution is so simple. I was getting really sad that after spending days creating a nice debugging workflow for mod_rewrite, something so basic was not working. :) As they say, hallelujah!

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you are missing the trailing `$` in your `RewriteRule` expression, hence stuff isn't matched fully?

You might want to consider switching to nginx; it has a very clear and reasonable documentation, without the bloat and nondeterminism that Apache is quite famous for.

Comment: Apache is extremely widely used, and recommending the requester switch to an entirely new application is counter-productive.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I finally found the answer: the `DPI` flag.